# Couldn't build the ios release after detach ExpoKit

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, ipa, expo

I've recently created a React Native app and have used Expo Camera api. My project was build via Create-React-Native-App. I wanted to create an unsigned ipa for ios, so I detached Expo so I could use Expo api and the native code both.

I've followed the Expo docs for proper detach and I then move towards pod install in my ios folder but whenever I tried to click build -> Archive, it starts giving an error:

> "Command /bin/sh/ failed with exit code 1".

When I double click it:

> [exp] Unable to read expokit version from podfile.lock. Make sure your
>   project depends on Expokit. Type error, cannot read 1 of null.

This is such confusing and frustrating and I couldn't get this solved after putting some filthy hours in it. I'm using Mac High Sierra and Xcode 9.2.

Comment: If you don't need to lock, try removing Podfile.lock

Comment: It needs a lock, the build -> archive command wants podfile.lock to check dependencies. It needs the Expokit version to proceed.

Comment: I meant - remove the Podfile.lock and rerun pod install to generate a new one.

Comment: I tried that too. It generates the same content again. It includes the cocoapods version and that's it.

Comment: Same here. Anyone resolve this? All It generates is the PODFILE CHECKSUM and the COCOAPODS version.